# Failed to read ...\Release\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Essentials.dll' with debugging symbols

Tags: xamarin.forms

Failed to read ...\Release\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Essentials.dll' with debugging symbols. Retrying to load it without it. Error details are logged below.

I made a project in Visual Studio 2019 Ete ... - the trial version has ended. And I installed Visual Studio 2019 Com ... When building, I get the following errors.
How to solve this problem?

```
Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolsNotMatchingException: Symbols were found but are not matching the assembly
   в Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols(ISymbolReader reader, Boolean throwIfSymbolsAreNotMaching)
   в Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
   в Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
   в Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Disposable`1 stream, String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   в Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   в Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   в Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.ReadAssembly(String file)
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Java.Interop.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Plugin.LocalNotifications.Abstractions.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLite-net.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Print.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
Directory obj\Release\90\android/assets contains Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
```

Comment: delete the bin/obj folders and build project again

Comment: @magicandre1981 Removed the "bin" and "obj" folders from the MyApp\MyApp folder

when assembling the above listed errors no. But when I do archiving, the same errors appear.

Comment: also deleted the "bin" and "obj" folders from the MyApp\MyApp.Android folder - did not help solve the problem.

Comment: solved the problem by reinstalling nuget packages for each platform. thanks

Comment: ok, post this as answer and later accept it